# How can I get a Referral code to be populated directly on friends first App launch(i.e. during signup) in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I get a Referral code to be populated directly on friends first App launch,i.e. during signup?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a deep link for your application and add a referral code into link. Usually, deep linking looks something like this:

```
referralapp://some_referral_code
```

So if a user opens the app by this link, you'll be able to retrieve `some_referral_code` using [React Native linking library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking). There is an example article on [Medium](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e).